# Cannot upload file to Azure blob storage using Azure functions Node

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions, serverless

**NOTE: There is no issue here, The issue was with my functions.json script file location. It was pointing to an old script file. The minute I pointed to a new one, it started working.**

I am not sure why this is happening, I have a try-catch block and the function never hits the catch block but the image I am trying upload never shows up in the container.

I am new to NODEJS. Since I cant achieve the same thing using C# functions, I decided to write it in the node.

Problem: Azure function Service bus topic trigger, take the message payload and grabs a screenshot of the page using puppeteer. The output from the buffer is in form of the buffer, I am trying to upload this to Azure storage blob.

```
import { AzureFunction, Context } from "@azure/functions";
import { ServiceBusMessage } from "@azure/service-bus";
import * as puppeteer from 'puppeteer';
import * as BlobServiceClient from "azure-storage";
import { Readable } from 'stream';

const serviceBusTopicTrigger: AzureFunction = async function (context: Context, mySbMsg: ServiceBusMessage): Promise<void> {
    try {
        const promotionId = context.bindingData.userProperties.promotionId;
        context.log('Player Screen Grabber ServiceBus topic trigger function processing message started', promotionId);
        const playerURL = process.env['playerURL'] + promotionId + '/';
        let browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
        let page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto(playerURL, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
        await page.setViewport({ width: 1920, height: 1080 });
        const screenshotBuffer = await page.screenshot({
            encoding: 'binary'
        });
        await page.close();
        await browser.close();
        const newPlayerScreenShotStream = new Readable({
            read() {
                this.push(screenshotBuffer);
            },
        });
        var fileName = promotionId + ".png";
        context.bindings.fileName = fileName;
        context.bindings.storage = screenshotBuffer;
        context.done();
        context.log('Player Screen Grabber ServiceBus topic trigger function processing message ended', promotionId);
    }
    catch (error) {
        throw error;
    }
};
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your infromation you provide, you want to use dymaic name in Azure function blob storage output bining. If so, we cannot use `context.bindings.<>` to implement it. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node?tabs=v2#bindings) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-output?tabs=javascript#usage)

If you want to implement it, you have the following two choices.

- [Using Azure Functions binding expression patterns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-expressions-patterns)

if you define the message's body as json, we can directly read the value with binding expression in function

For example

My message

[image]

function.json

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "mySbMsg",
      "type": "serviceBusTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "topicName": "",
      "subscriptionName": "",
      "connection": "MYSERVICEBUS"
    },
    {
      "type": "blob",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "outputBlob",
      "path": "outcontainer/{fileName}.png",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage"
    }
  ],
  "scriptFile": "../dist/ServiceBusTopicTrigger1/index.js"
}
```

Function code

```
import { AzureFunction, Context } from "@azure/functions";
import * as puppeteer from "puppeteer";

const serviceBusTopicTrigger: AzureFunction = async function (
  context: Context,
  mySbMsg: any
): Promise<void> {
  try {
    context.log("ServiceBus topic trigger function processed message", mySbMsg);
    const promotionId = context.bindingData.userProperties.promotionId;

    const playerURL =
      "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node?tabs=v2";
    let browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
    let page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(playerURL, { waitUntil: "networkidle2" });
    await page.setViewport({ width: 1920, height: 1080 });
    const screenshotBuffer = await page.screenshot({
      encoding: "binary",
    });
    await page.close();
    await browser.close();
    context.bindings.outputBlob = screenshotBuffer;
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
};

export default serviceBusTopicTrigger;
```

[image]

[image]

- Using Azure Blob storage sdk
  Function code

```
import { AzureFunction, Context } from "@azure/functions";
import * as puppeteer from "puppeteer";
import { BlobServiceClient } from "@azure/storage-blob";
const serviceBusTopicTrigger: AzureFunction = async function (
  context: Context,
  mySbMsg: any
): Promise<void> {
  try {
    context.log("ServiceBus topic trigger function processed message", mySbMsg);
    const promotionId = context.bindingData.userProperties.promotionId;

    const playerURL =
      "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node?tabs=v2";
    let browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });
    let page = await browser.newPage();
    await page.goto(playerURL, { waitUntil: "networkidle2" });
    await page.setViewport({ width: 1920, height: 1080 });
    const screenshotBuffer = await page.screenshot({
      encoding: "binary",
    });
    await page.close();
    await browser.close();
    // the storage account connection string
    const constr = process.env["AzureWebJobsStorage"];
    const blobserviceClient = BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString(constr);
    const containerClient = blobserviceClient.getContainerClient("output");
    const blob = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(`${promotionId}.png`);
    await blob.uploadData(screenshotBuffer);
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
};

export default serviceBusTopicTrigger;
```

My message
[image]

Result
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. After digging, I realised that the issue is with functions.json script file location. It was running an old script.